# Prove that the following is a homomorphism:

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-homomorphism

Define $\theta: R[x] \to R[x]$as $\theta(f)=f'$.

I understand the basics but I'm not sure I'm doing this correctly.  I know first we have to show that the function is well defined, so we take 2 distinct elements from the domain.  So would $x_1^2$, $x_2^2$ work?  Where $(x_1)^2 = (x_2)^2$.

Then $((x_1)^2)'= ((x_2)^2)'$.
So $\theta(x_1)=\theta(x_2)$.

I just feel like this is wrong.  Any suggestions?

Comment: For well-definedness: you should start with two *arbitrary* polynomials, say $f$ and $g$ in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ such that $f=g$, then show that $\theta(f)=\theta(g)$.

Comment: facepalm.  That feels a lot more natural.  Thank you so much @Anurag A!

Comment: You should specify the group structure on $\Bbb R[x]$. Note: differentiation preserves the additive structure (moreover, it's $\Bbb R$-linear), but doesn't preserve multiplication (though $\Bbb R[x]$ is not even a group under multiplication).